# The following classes could not be found: - android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-textinputlayout

I'm trying to use TextInputLayout for edittext.
I followed steps from below link.. 
[Using TextInputLayout](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-login-screen-using-textinputlayout--cms-24168)
Still I'm facing below error:

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

I also have added dependencies in build.gradle file..

What else I'm missing.. Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Check support library whether in external libraries.

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

and rebuild the project.

Comment: I am facing the issue... Please help me